# FreeBSD Python missing header files

Tags: python, freebsd, pip

I am using FreeBSD 11, Python 3.7, and clang 8.0.0, and I am trying to install Python packages using `pip`. But when I try to install a package, for example `pycurl`, I get an error saying it can't find the C header file `limits.h`.

I use this command to install `pycurl`:

```
pip3.7 install pycurl
```

Error:

```
In file included from src/pycurl.h:5:<br/>
/usr/local/include/python3.7m/Python.h:11:10: fatal error: 'limits.h' file not found
#include <limits.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

In an effort to get the missing header files I have installed the following FreeBSD packages:

- amd64-binutils-2.33.1_2,1
- amd64-gcc-6.4.0_8
- amd64-xtoolchain-gcc-0.4_1
- llvm-devel-11.0.d20200519    # Yes I know that this one is not helpful, but I am getting desperate
- mpc-1.1.0_2
- mpfr-4.0.2
- xtoolchain-llvm80-0.1

This installs the `limits.h` file, but now when I compile it fails to find `syslimits.h`.

I used this command to install `pycurl`:

```
pip3.7 install --global-option=build_ext --global-option=/x86_64-portbllib/gcc9/gcc/x86_64-portbld-tools/include/" pycurl
```

Error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/python3.7m/Python.h:11:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-freebsd11.3/6.4.0/install-tools/include/limits.h:34:10: fatal error: 'syslimits.h' file not found
#include "syslimits.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

What packages do I need to install in order to install Python packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official FreeBSD packages already contain `ftp/py-pycurl` package. Do you really need to compile it yourself?

If you do, I recommend installing FreeBSD Ports tree and running `make -C /usr/ports/ftp/py-pycurl build` command to see exactly how it is built. This should give an idea what are you doing wrong when compiling manually.

Comment: Mostly because I am used to using `pip` to install Python packages. And a quick search in the FreeBSD packages I couldn't find it. But a thorough search showed me it was there.